# Set logo for Mac application

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I am an iOS developer and did my first Cocoa Mac application using Xcode 4.2, I set the Logo image in the xcode itself and property list, but the application logo still has its default logo (the white sheet with two pens), how can I set Logo for my application?

Comment: The correct term for that is the icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Design your 512x512 icon and save it as png file. Open Icon Composer (installed with Xcode in /Developer/Applications/Utilities folder) and drag your png file to it and save your icon as icns.

Now in Xcode open your project and select the target. Drag your icns file to the "App Icon" box. That´s it! Build and run again...

Answer (score 0):

You should place icon (icns format file) Your project target -> summary -> drag n drop in App icon box.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need a .icns file rather than a straight png to get the file icon. This is essentially a collection of images at different sizes that mac os can use for different jobs.

as of mountain lion, the Icon Composer isn't available. You can build your icns file on the command line from a bunch of scaled and named bitmaps, or you can use the simple utility I built to do the job!

http://hobbyistsoftware.com/icnsBuilder